# Dynamics CRM Workflow updating closed letter after Mail Merge

Tags: workflow-foundation, dynamics-crm, crm

Dynamics CRM Workflow updating closed letter after Mail MergeZones: 
Microsoft Dynamics, CRM Software

I have created a new entity (Fund Member) to create a many to many relationship between Contact and a new entity called Fund. Users will be running mail merges from this entity either via Advanced find, or associated views from  the Contact or Fund entity. When the activity is created, the default regarding is the Fund Member record, and the recipient is blank. We need recipient to be populated with the contact and the regarding to be populated with the fund. To do this I have created a workflow described below.

The workflow changes the recipient and regarding for a Letter Activity after the activity has been created. To do this, the workflow has to change the activity status to Open, update the activity, then reclose it.

This works when a letter is created for a single contact, but when applied to multiple contacts, some of the instances complete, but most of them get stuck in the 'Wait' status, and on further investigation they have failed after opening the activity with a with  "SQL error has occured" message.

I improved the success rate to only the occasional error by including a wait timout of 1 minute between the status change and the update, but this isn't a totally risk free solution.

HAs anyone else experienced this issue and developed a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer.

We put a support ticket with MS. And found some very intensive sql. this has been fixed in rollup 6

Answer (score 0):

From your above description, i assumed that you're not using custom workflow activity, and only using the built in workflow designer in CRM.

Could you please enable the Dynamics CRM Trace as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490). You might find the detail error message somewhere inside the trace log.